# using Auth0 in angular2 with routeConfig enabled

Tags: angular, auth0

I have a problem, I hope some of you can answer, cause I can't find a solution on google. Right now, I'm trying implement Auth0 authentication to my application.

To make this clear, I have created an App component which looks like this:

**App Component**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app',
template: `
<div>
    <div class="header wrapper">
        <header class="row">
            <div class="column small-12">
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="/assets/img/logo.svg" title="" />
                </a>
                <a class="navigation-toggle icon-menu hide-for-large-up" (click)="toggleMenuState()" ></a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <div class="footer wrapper">
        <footer class="row">
            <div class="column small-12">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="icon icon-ship hide-for-medium-down"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
`,
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet, AmendmentComponent, AmendmentAccountComponent ]
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/amendment/...', name: 'Amendment', component:    AmendmentComponent, useAsDefault: true }    
])
```

Have added the routeConfig, so right now the URL look like this: ***localhost:3000/amendment***

Then I have created a amendmentComponent which look like this:

```
@Component({
selector: 'amendment',
template: `  
        <div class="help wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="column small-12">
                    <amendment-account></amendment-account>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-area wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
`,
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet, AmendmentAccountComponent, BookingsComponent, MainComponent, RegisterOrLoginComponent ],
styles: [`
    agent {
        display: block;
    }
`]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/amendment/', name: 'Bookings', component: BookingsComponent,  useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/bookings', name: 'Bookings', component: BookingsComponent },
    { path: '/main/:id', name: 'Main', component: MainComponent },
    { path: '/main', redirectTo: ["Bookings"] },
])
```

In the HTML, you can see that i'm loading the component  (AccountComponent). I'm handling the Auth0 in this component.

AccountComponent html looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#" *ngIf="!loggedIn()" (click)="login()">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#" *ngIf="loggedIn()" (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
```

What I'm trying to make, is to load the Auth0 box on localhost:3000/amendment/login Url. This doesn't works for me, cause when I click the login Href link, the goes fast to the localhost:3000/amendment/bookings because of the RouterConfig :(

So my problem is that it don't stop and load the Auth0 login box. I can see it for a split second, and then it redirect me.

Any solution for this?

Notice that it works if I remove all routerConfig paths, so no redirection happens, but that is not a solution for me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess

```
(click)="login(); false"
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: Wow.. that was an easy solution.. Could you explain what it does? (stop redirecting i guess)???

Comment: It disables the default behavior of the `<a href="#">` to make it execute `login()` only. If the event handler returns false, Angular calls `event.preventDefault();` on the event.